# Installing Python Package in AWS Lambda Layer

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I have a python script which is running on my local machine and I want to move it to AWS Lambda for periodic execution. I have 3 import statements in the script for which I am adding layers but facing some issues.

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date
```

For googleapiclient api, I downloaded it in a folder and uploaded to AWS layer and lambda is able to find this module. I wanted to use this along with AWS Data wrangler package but running into layer size restriction issues. So I downloaded pandas to the same folder as google api and then uploaded the zip file to layer. But now I am get a numpy dependency error though numpy was downloaded as part of pandas install. Two folders as part of my libraries folder are numpy, numpy-1.22.0.dist-info which is correct version as per error message below. I also tried downloading numpy separately in same package but that's also not working. The Python version that I am using in Lambda is 3.7.

Please let me know if I am missing something and if this is the correct approach for installing python packages for AWS Lambda. There are some solutions available with regards to using a container for this but I am not well versed with containers. So just wanted to check if there is some fix through which I can achieve this or is containers the way to go about it.

Below is the error message:

> Response { "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function':
> Unable to import required dependencies:\nnumpy: \n\nIMPORTANT: PLEASE
> READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!\n\nImporting the
> numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for\nmany reasons,
> often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was\ninstalled.\n\nWe
> have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:\n\n
> [https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html\n\nPlease](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html%5Cn%5CnPlease)
> note and check the following:\n\n The Python version is: Python3.7
> from "/var/lang/bin/python3.7"\n The NumPy version is:
> "1.22.0"\n\nand make sure that they are the versions you
> expect.\nPlease carefully study the documentation linked above for
> further help.\n\nOriginal error was: No module named
> 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'\n", "errorType":
> "Runtime.ImportModuleError", "stackTrace": [] }
>
> Function Logs START RequestId: d......-........-.....d
> Version: $LATEST ERROR Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import
> module 'lambda_function': Unable to import required dependencies:
> numpy: IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS
> ISSUE! Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen
> for many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
> installed. We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting
> tips at:
> https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html Please
> note and check the following:
>
> The Python version is: Python3.7 from "/var/lang/bin/python3.7" The
> NumPy version is: "1.22.0" and make sure that they are the versions
> you expect. Please carefully study the documentation linked above for
> further help. Original error was: No module named
> 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath' Traceback (most recent call last): END
> RequestId: de72............................6d REPORT RequestId:
> de72............................6d Duration: 1.68 ms Billed
> Duration: 2 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 55 MB Init
> Duration: 570.09 ms Request ID de72............................6d

Regards,  Dbeings

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was building the pandas package on windows machine and uploading it to AWS layer. Building the package on EC2 and then putting it on AWS layer fixed the issue.